# Angular interceptor will not call out (POST)

Tags: angular

Using Angular 10. My error.interceptor.ts file will not call out.
Notice 'this.http.post(url, body, httpOptions);' this does not get called?
I'm not sure why?

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpRequest, HttpHandler, HttpEvent, HttpInterceptor, HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable, throwError } from 'rxjs';
import { catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { AlertService } from '../../dashboard/alert/alert.service';
import { AuthService } from '../auth/auth.service';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { GlobalService } from '../api/global.service';

@Injectable()

export class ErrorInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

constructor(
    private alertService: AlertService,
    private http: HttpClient
    ) {}

intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {

    return next.handle(request).pipe(

        catchError(err => {
        let error = 'Ut oh, there was an error mate...';

        if (err.error != null) {
            if (err.statusText) {
                error = err.statusText;
            }

            if (err.message) {
                error += ': ' + err.message;
            }
        }

        if (err.status === 401) {
            // console.log("error 401");
            // auto logout if 401 response returned from api
            // this.authenticationService.logout();
            // location.reload(true);
        }

        //
        const url = 'log/logEvent';
        const body = 'test';
        const httpOptions = {
          headers: new HttpHeaders({
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          })
        };

        this.http.post<any>(url, body, httpOptions);

        // Send error to the view for alert
        this.alertService.error(error);
        return throwError(error);
    }));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you register it in the App.module? :)
Should look like this:

```
providers: [{ provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: ErrorInterceptor, multi: true }]
```

edit:

I think it's just the missing subscription. Your call should look something like this:

`this.http.post(url, body, httpOptions).subscribe((res) => null)`

Comment: Yes, the interceptor works just fine. It simply won't do: this.http.post<any>(url, body, httpOptions);

Comment: Hmm alright, what about the rest? Does it catch any error?

Comment: It does catch the error. So then I want to send the error to the serve to be logged, but it won't POST?

Comment: On my, forget to subscribe! Thank you!

Comment: Know this issue haha no problem!

Answer (score 0):

Interceptors work on all requests, manipulating or reading data from them.

If you are using custome module then you should import it in cusotme.module.ts file otherwise import it in app.module.ts to make interceptor work

```
providers: [
 MyService,
 MyOtherService,
 ...,
 AuthGuard,    // <- implements canActivate
 RoleGuard,    // <- implements canActivate
 ...,
 // Interceptor 
 {
    provide : HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
    useClass : TokenInterceptor, // Your intercepter
    multi : true
 }
 ],
 // continue...
 ],
```